# Numerically Integrating a Hamiltonian but getting different results when compared with alternative equivalent equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, variational-calculus

currently trying to perform an integration of the Hamiltonian for a Schwarzschild black hole. However, I'm coming up short.

The code is as follows:

```
   ClearAll["Global`*"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];

(*Symplectic schemes*)
q = {t[s], r[s], \[Theta][s], \[Phi][s]};
p = D[q, s];
n = Length[q];
tt = 1 - 2 m/r[s];
rr = -1/tt;
\[Theta]\[Theta] = -r[s]^2;
\[Phi]\[Phi] = -(r[s] Sin[\[Theta][s]])^2;
metric = {{tt, 0, 0, 0}, {0, rr, 0, 0}, {0, 0, \[Theta]\[Theta], 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, \[Phi]\[Phi]}};
inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]];
ivs = {1.3, 0, 0, 0.088}; ics = {0, 6.5, \[Pi]/2, 0};
m = 1;

hamiltonian = 1/2 (D[q, s].inversemetric.D[q, s]) == 1;
pdot = Table[-D[hamiltonian, q[[i]]], {i, 1, n}];
qdot = Table[ D[hamiltonian, p[[i]]], {i, 1, n}];

eqs1 = {{qdot, pdot}, {ics, ivs}};

invariants = hamiltonian;
time = {T, 0, 100};
solee = NDSolve[eqs1, q, time, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", 
  StartingStepSize -> 0.1]
```

However, when I attempt to numerically integrate I get the following message:

```
NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of -True in the first argument {{{(t^\[Prime])[s]/(1+Times[<<2>>])==0,(-1+2 Power[<<2>>]) (r^\[Prime])[s]==0,-((\[Theta]^\[Prime])[s]/r[s]^2)==0,-((Csc[\[Theta][<<1>>]]^2 (\[Phi]^\[Prime])[s])/r[s]^2)==0},{-True,-(1/2 (Times[<<3>>]+Times[<<4>>]+Times[<<3>>]+Times[<<4>>])==0),-((Cot[\[Theta][<<1>>]] Csc[<<1>>]^2 (<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>]^2)/r[<<1>>]^2==0),-True}},{{0,6.5,\[Pi]/2,0},{1.3,0,0,0.088}}}.
```

**UPDATE** (initial problem solved)
Following the excellent answer below, we can see that the singularity which occurs at `r=2`  which is reached around `s=10..`.

Now, I have written a version of [this code](https://www.physics.uci.edu/~etolleru/KerrOrbitProject.pdf) which performs integration of the *geodesic equations of motion* (as opposed to the Hamiltonian equations above) under the same initial conditions. However, there is no singularity reached for this and the results are clearly different. The results should be equivalent! I am not too sure what is the issue.

Comment: In the code you posted, `coords` is undefined.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveSPRK.html)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 good spot!! That's what I get from dropping and dragging from my other codes and not being careful. However, when I attempt to numerically integrate after correcting the undefined `coords` it still does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd prefer to know exactly what code you have for `coords` that produces a null result for `pdot` and `qdot`, before speculating about what's wrong.  Could you edit your question and include the code for `coords`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 apologies for not being clear. I have two separate codes for almost the same problem. In one code I have named coords = `[t,r,\theta,\phi]` (or something to that effect) and I blindly copied that part over to my new code. Hence the `coords` is really just `q` in generalised coordinates.  I've edited the code to be more legible.

Comment: `D[hamiltonian, q[[1]]]` returns true instead of an equation, that's what ndsolve complains about in the message

Comment: and have you seen the output of rr or tt? it's an array with half a million elements. I think you want to define a function istead, no?

Comment: @tsuresuregusa  I definitely would like to define a function. I'm initially interested in seeing what happens for this specific case though. However, as you can see, failing miserably!

Comment: @tsuresuregusa how did you see that there are half a million elements?

Comment: `Dimensions[tt]` I tried writing them as functions but it killed my kernel, let me try again in a bit.

Comment: Does it make sense that `t[s]` might go to infinity around `s = 10.8`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I believe `t[s]` would tend to infinity as `r[s] -> 2`

Comment: Are you aware that `NDSolve[]` supports symplectic RK methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my guess at how it should be done.  There were a couple of changes.  You need separate `q` and `p` variables in order to write the Hamiltonian and set up the corresponding equations.

```
(*Symplectic schemes*)
Clear[m];
q = {t[s], r[s], θ[s], ϕ[s]};
(*p=D[q,s];*)
p = {pt[s], pr[s], pθ[s], pϕ[s]};                 (* use explicit p variables *)
n = Length[q];
tt = 1 - 2 m/r[s];
rr = -1/tt;
θθ = -r[s]^2;
ϕϕ = -(r[s] Sin[θ[s]])^2;
metric = {{tt, 0, 0, 0}, {0, rr, 0, 0}, {0, 0, θθ, 0}, {0, 0, 0, ϕϕ}};
inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]];
ivs = {1.3, 0, 0, 0.088}; ics = {0, 6.5, π/2, 0};
m = 1;

(*hamiltonian=1/2 (D[q,s].inversemetric.D[q,s])-1;*)

hamiltonian = 1/2 (p.inversemetric.p) - 1;        (* define H in terms of p, q *)
pdot = Table[-D[hamiltonian, q[[i]]], {i, 1, n}];
qdot = Table[D[hamiltonian, p[[i]]], {i, 1, n}];

eqs1 = {{D[q, s] == qdot, D[p, s] == pdot},       (* adjust equations to new defs *)
  {(q /. s -> 0) == ics, (p /. s -> 0) == ivs}};

invariants = hamiltonian;
time = {s, 0, 100};                               (* change T to s to match q etc. *)
solee = NDSolve[eqs1, q, time, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", 
  StartingStepSize -> 0.1]
```

> NDSolve::ndstf: At s == 10.620493252880072`, system appears to be stiff. Methods Automatic, BDF, or StiffnessSwitching may be more appropriate.

```
ListLinePlot[Head /@ (q /. First@solee), PlotRange -> {-0.5, 30}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You get a slightly better result with a Gauss-Legendre collocation method of moderate order:

```
solee = NDSolve[eqs1, Head /@ q, time, 
  Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 6, 
    "Coefficients" -> "ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients"}]
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At s == 10.834214056862363`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta"` method could not be used because the system did not appear to be separable.  I did not look further into it.

Comment: Wow. Very nice. Although I am confused. I have an alternate code where I integrate the geodesic equation with the same initial conditions using an explicit runge kutta, however, I get different results? They should be equivalent. For one, there is no singularity observed at all.... Hmmmm, I will need to keep checking to see what is going on.

Comment: So, for one simulation which uses a code I wrote adopted from [here](https://www.physics.uci.edu/~etolleru/KerrOrbitProject.pdf)  the orbit never approaches the singularity located at r=2 and looks okay. For the above method the singularity is reached? I'm not entirely sure why this is happening.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin I got equivalent results with both the explicit and implicit RK methods (as shown in my answer). My plot looks like the plot at the top of page 9 of the Tollerud pdf, singularity and all. Maybe it's like that or maybe there's a difference in the matrix or the ICs. My first guess is that the difference is not due to the numerical method but is in the math.

Comment: from what I believe the output should be equivalent to the output at the bottom of pg. 7 and the top of page 8 of the Tollerud pdf. What we have is a particle with angular velocity 0.088 starting at r=6.5 so it should make some sort of orbit shape! But I am not sure why it is not doing that. Although your answer is fantastic and much appreciated.