# How to formulate the Hamiltonian equations of motion? Part II

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, variational-calculus

I've recently asked a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147612/numerically-integrating-a-hamiltonian-but-getting-different-results-when-compare/147618?noredirect=1#comment396653_147618) on an issue I was facing with numerically integrating Hamiltonian equations of motion. I got a great answer.

Following on from this, I wanted to write a very similar code using alternate definitions in variational mechanics.

That is using the following:

1. The Lagrangian is given by $L= \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu} \dot{x}^\mu(s) \dot{x}^\nu(s) $
2. The generalised coordinates are given by $x^\mu(s)$ with velocity given by $ \dot{x}^\mu(s)$.
3. The conjugate momentum is given by $p = \partial L\;/ \;\partial \dot{x}^\mu(s)$
4. The Hamiltonian is given by $H=p\dot{x} - L$ or $H=\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu\nu} p_\mu p_\nu $.
5. Hamilton's equations are given by $\dot{p} = -g^{\mu\nu}\partial_q H, \; \dot{q} = g^{\mu\nu}\partial_p H$

Now, with the help of @jjc385 I think it is almost there. however, I still can't seem to finalise the equations of motion. I know they are getting there because I can compare them with the geodesic equations of motion for the same problem. (There is a reason why I'm being awkward and proceeding this way). The updated code thanks to @jjc385 is now given by:

```
SetAttributes[m, Constant];
q = {t[s], r[s], \[Theta][s], \[Phi][s]};
vel = D[q, s];
n = Length[q];
tt = 1 - 2 m/r[s];
rr = -1/tt;
\[Theta]\[Theta] = -r[s]^2;
\[Phi]\[Phi] = -(r[s] Sin[\[Theta][s]])^2;
metric = {{tt, 0, 0, 0}, {0, rr, 0, 0}, {0, 0, \[Theta]\[Theta], 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, \[Phi]\[Phi]}};
inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]];

p = FullSimplify[Table[D[L, vel[[i]]], {i, 1, n}]];

H = FullSimplify[1/2*(p.inversemetric.p)];
pSym = Symbol@*(StringJoin["p" <> #] &)@*ToString@*Head /@ q;
Solve[pSym == p, vel]
Hnew = H /. Flatten@%;

ivsnew = {1.3, 0, 0, 0.088}; ics = {0, 6.5, \[Pi]/2, 0};
m = 1;

pdot = FullSimplify[inversemetric.Table[-D[H, q[[i]]], {i, 1, n}]]
qdot = inversemetric.Table[D[Hnew, pSym[[i]]], {i, 1, n}]
eqs1 = {{D[q, s] == qdot, 
    D[p, s] == pdot}, {(q /. s -> 0) == ics, (p /. s -> 0) == 
     ivsnew}};
time = {s, 0, 750};
solee = NDSolve[eqs1, q, time, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"];
```

Any suggestions?

I know the equations of motion are incorrect but I don't know how to make them correct!

Comment: You should be able to tell that `pdot=...` works without a problem, but `qdot=...` does not.  As Mathematica is trying to tell you with the error messages, when you try to differentiate `H` with respect to `p[1]`, `p[1]` evaluates to a long expression -- Mathematica can't hope to differentiate with respect to that.

Comment: @jjc385 I can see that. However, do you have any idea of how to fix that?

Comment: @jjc385 I wish that was the issue. That was just a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I think `p=...` has a typo, and should read

```
p = FullSimplify[Table[D[L, vel[[i]]], {i, 1, n}]]
```

---

One way to use Hamilton's equations of motions is to solve for the (symbolic) conjugate momenta in terms of `q[[i]]`:

```
pSym = Symbol@*(StringJoin["p" <> #] &)@*ToString@*Head /@ q
```

> ```
> {pt, pr, pθ, pϕ}
> ```

```
Solve[pSym == p], vel]
```

> ```
> {{ t'[s] -> pt * ... , r'[s] -> pr * ..., ... }}
> ```

Now you can write `H` as an explicit function of the symbolic conjugate momenta:

```
Hnew = H /. Flatten@%
```

Finally, you can do

```
qdot = inversemetric.Table[D[Hnew, pSym[[i]] ], {i, 1, n}]
```

which will be a function of the elements of `vel` and `pSym`.  Hopefully the equation solving will proceed as you wish.

---

**Edit1:**  You might find the last line simpler using either of the following, which all give the same output as the original:

```
qdot = inversemetric.Table[ D[Hnew, pi], {pi, pSym} ]
qdot = inversemetric.( D[Hnew,#]& /@ pSym )
```

__

**Edit2/ Significant Addition:**

When using Hamilton's equations of motion, your independent variables are $p$ and $q$ -- $\dot{q}$ should not appear at all.

First, it helps to write the components of `pSym` as functions of `s`,
like you did for `q` :

```
pSym = #[s] & /@ (Symbol@*(StringJoin["p" <> #] &)@*ToString@*Head /@ q)
```

> ```
> {pt[s], pr[s], pθ[s], pϕ[s]}
> ```

You should find `pdot` in terms of $p$ rather than $\dot{q}$ :

```
pdot = FullSimplify[inversemetric.Table[-D[Hnew, q[[i]]], {i, 1, n}]]
```

Then you can integrate the equations of motion:

```
eqs = { {D[pSym, s] == pdot, D[q, s] == qdot}, 
        {(q /. s -> 0) == ics, (pSym /. s -> 0) == ivsnew}  };
NSolve[ eqs, time, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta" ]
```

I'm not 100% confident with the output, but at least it's giving something that seems somewhat reasonable.

---

Update:  The full code I'm using:

```
SetAttributes[m, Constant];
q = {t[s], r[s], \[Theta][s], \[Phi][s]};
vel = D[q, s];
n = Length[q];
tt = 1 - 2 m/r[s];
rr = -1/tt;
\[Theta]\[Theta] = -r[s]^2;
\[Phi]\[Phi] = -(r[s] Sin[\[Theta][s]])^2;
metric = {{tt, 0, 0, 0}, {0, rr, 0, 0}, 
          {0, 0, \[Theta]\[Theta], 0}, {0, 0, 0, \[Phi]\[Phi]}};
inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]];
L = FullSimplify[1/2 vel.metric.vel];

p = FullSimplify[Table[D[L, vel[[i]]], {i, 1, n}]];

H = FullSimplify[1/2*(p.inversemetric.p)]
pSym = #[s] & /@ (Symbol@*(StringJoin["p" <> #] &)@*ToString@*Head /@ q)
Solve[pSym == p, vel]
Hnew = H /. Flatten@%

ivsnew = {1.3, 0, 0, 0.088}; ics = {0, 6.5, \[Pi]/2, 0};
m = 1;

pdot = FullSimplify[inversemetric.Table[-D[Hnew, q[[i]]], {i, 1, n}]]
qdot = inversemetric.Table[D[Hnew, pSym[[i]]], {i, 1, n}]
time = {s, 0, 750};
eqs = {{D[pSym, s] == pdot, 
    D[q, s] == qdot}, {(q /. s -> 0) == ics, (pSym /. s -> 0) == 
     ivsnew}};
NDSolve[eqs, pSym, time, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"]
```

Comment: It is almost perfect with the help of that great answer. However, I am still coming up short! I can see the equations of motion are beginning to take the same form as if I were to approach the problem using the geodesic equations of motion. I've updated the question hopefully for the final time. I'd love if you could take a look. Your answer helped a lot!!

Comment: @Rumplestillskin See my edit.  Now `NDSolve` is producing output.

Comment: I don't know why but the output is still wrong!!! This is far more challenging that I first though. Thanks again for the output. The r[s] variable should be period with a stable orbit!! I haven't got the faintest clue why this isn't working!

Comment: @Rumplestillskin (Ignore the now-deleted comment about the code not working -- I was accidentally using `NSolve` rather than `NDSolve`.)  My most recent edit was just to fix a typo in `eqs`, and post my full code.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin Note that one can find explicit expressions for $\dot{q}$ and $\dot{p}$ very easily by hand:  $\dot{q}^\nu = p_\mu g^{\mu\nu}$ and $\dot{p}_\mu = -\frac{1}{2} p_\alpha p_\beta \partial_\mu g^{\alpha\beta}$.  I calculated `pdot` and `qdot` with these expressions directly, and I seem to be getting the same numerical result.  Anyway, I don't think I have time to work on this further for now.  Good luck.